# Delete an object from a list of objects in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, object

I have a list of objects.

My list format:

```
my_list = [
    {
        "y": "9",
        "x": "num.nine"
    },
    {
        "y": "8",
        "x": "eight"
    },
    {
        "y": "7",
        "x": "num.seven"
    },
    {
        "y": "6",
        "x": "six"
    },
    {
        "y": "5",
        "x": "num.five"
    }
]
```

I want to delete the objects where `my_list['x']` is not like `num`.

This is what I did:

```
for val in my_list:
    if('num' not in val['x']):
        del val['x']
        del val['y']

pprint(my_list)
```

The result of that code is:

```
[
 {'x': 'num.nine', 'y': '9'},
 {},
 {'x': 'num.seven', 'y': '7'},
 {},
 {'x': 'num.five', 'y': '5'}
]
```

How do I delete the whole object?

My expected result is:

```
[
 {'x': 'num.nine', 'y': '9'},
 {'x': 'num.seven', 'y': '7'},
 {'x': 'num.five', 'y': '5'}
]
```

Comment: `my_list = [obj for obj in my_list if obj['x'].startswith('num.')]`

Comment: list comprehension only returning entries you want, or for loop making a COPY and using my_list.delete, deleting the entries you dont want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why delete? Alternatively

```
my_list = [val for val in my_list if 'num' in val['x']]
```

You can use filter function as well. (Note that filter in python2 returns a list, and in python3 it returns a iterator)

PS. I am not sure whether the filter condition you have written is exactly what you need, yet I have used the same condition. Most likely you want to include val when val['x'] is starting with "num."

Comment: Terminology note, `filter` returns an iterator, not a generator.

Answer (score 1):

Add what you need to a new list:

```
new_list = []
for elem in my_list:
    if('num' in elem['x']):
        new_list.append(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using list comprehension, this would be the answer:

```
new_list = [obj for obj in my_list if 'num' in obj['x']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient thing to is probably to use the [Python filter function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). Consider this example:

```
>>> my_list = my_list=[ 
         { 
             "y": "9", 
             "x": "num.nine" 
         }, 
         { 
             "y": "8", 
             "x": "eight" 
         }, 
         { 
             "y": "7", 
             "x": "num.seven" 
         }, 
         { 
             "y": "6", 
             "x": "six" 
         }, 
         { 
             "y": "5", 
             "x": "num.five" 
         } 
    ]                                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> my_list = list(filter(lambda item: 'num' in item['x'], my_list))                                                                                                                           
>>> my_list                                                                                                                                                                                    
[{'y': '9', 'x': 'num.nine'},
 {'y': '7', 'x': 'num.seven'},
 {'y': '5', 'x': 'num.five'}]
```

Note that you're creating a new list with this approach, rather than modifying the old one in place. That's probably a better approach, because if you simultaneously iterate over an object while also modifying it, you'll get surprising results.

Comment: In my experience `filter()` is measurably slower than a list comprehension.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, depends on size of initial list. In one of questions I've seen detailed test, but not sure if I can find link now. **Upd.** Tested with timeit and my simple test shows that list comprehension is slightly slower *(I used list with 200 dictionaries for test)*.

Comment: I would be interested to see that @OlvinRoght — with the kind of data and filter in this question, the comprehension is considerably faster whether the list has 5 items or 100000.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I think that's what I just said. I *did* test it. Comprehension was faster regardless of list size.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, as well a I am ([code](https://repl.it/repls/PapayawhipAmbitiousGraphs))

Comment: The reason a list comprehension may not be more efficient is that if the list is especially large, and you don't cast the output of `filter()` to a list, you can iterate sequentially over the return value of `filter()` and it won't have to hold a new list in memory or build it ahead of time.

Comment: @OlvinRoght when I run your code, I get 1.6692464520019712 (comprehension), 
2.425171966002381 (filter).

Comment: Agreed @KenKinder, if you are not going to make a list, generators/iterators etc. are great.

Comment: @KenKinder, actually you can replace brackets with parentheses and it will create generator :)

Comment: @OlvinRoght What?? That's a thing?

Comment: @KenKinder, I mean that alternatively you can use `(obj for obj in my_list if obj['x'].startswith('num.'))` which also won't create list in memory.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Woah! I had no idea. Thanks! TIL!